# SSRS - show and hide based on expression drill down subreport

Tags: reporting-services, drillthrough

See the below sample image url. I created the main report having four details with toggle to drill down the sub report. If I click the **Detail1** the subreport1 will expand drill down then I click **Detail2** the subreport2 to be expand. But still the subreport1 is visible I want to collapse Subreort1 once click toggle second and vice versa.

Please give your suggetions. Advance thanks to all!!!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPd7u.jpg

Comment: I don't think it's going to be easy to do this.  Why not just leave it to the user to collapse the subreport they don't want to see anymore?

Comment: the report data is too long. so the user will confuse while all the items toggled.

Comment: Is there any expression to do like this?

Comment: No expression that I know of.  It could be done by setting an action on the + sign and going to the same report but setting parameters which indicate which trees should be collapsed/expanded.